# react-pdf/renderer - Image is shown in PDF preview but not in PDF file after download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, qr-code, react-pdf

I'm using `react-pdf/renderer` in my project, to generate PDF document and download it. I had to generate QRCode and insert it into document, so I used `qrcode` package and `toDataURL` method to  get `base64` string and pass it to `react-pdf/renderer`'s built in `Image` component (as known, user is not able to use custom components in this lib's Document, only predefined). Also tried to generate data buffer according to [documentation](https://react-pdf.org/components#source-object) and it shows QRCode normally in preview component but when I download document (using `PDFDownloadLink` from package) QRCode image is missing. All other images in document are displayed normally too, but they are assets images located in project's folder. Also added `allowDangerousPaths={true}` on built in `Image` component that should display QRCode but unsuccessful. Anyone help?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Found any solution?